# Net Use Doesn't Work For Second NIC In Windows 7 Pro Computer

Tags: windows, nic, multi-homed

I have an Intel E1G42ET Gigabit ET Dual Port Server Adapter installed in a Windows 7 Pro computer (NOT a Windows Server, just a plain old Windows 7 Pro computer).  I have setup a 192.168.1.0 network on one port of the Intel adapter and a 192.168.3.0 network on the other port of the adapter.

The 192.168.1.0 network is a DHCP network connected to a Linksys consumer router (DHCP is on the router) that connects to the Internet and has one Windows 7 machine connected to the network.

The 192.168.3.0 network is a static IP network and has one Windows 10 machine connected to the network.  The static IPv4 configuration for the 192.168.3.0 **Intel NIC port** is 192.168.3.2/255.255.255.0 and NO gateway IP address.  The static IPv4 configuration for the Windows 10 machine is 192.168.3.3/255.255.255.0 and NO gateway address.  I can successfully ping both the 192.168.3.2 and 192.168.3.3 computers from the Windows 7 Pro machine where the Intel NIC is installed.

I have a Windows .CMD script that uses `net use` to create a drive mapping on the 192.168.1.0 Windows 7 computer (from the Windows 7 Pro computer where the Intel NIC is installed) and it works fine.  I have a second Windows .CMD script that attempts to create a drive mapping using `net use` on the Windows 10 computer attached to the 192.168.3.0 network (also from the Windows 7 Pro computer where the Intel NIC is installed) but the .CMD file just hangs with a blinking cursor.

I suspect this is a routing issue.  Here is the `route print` output from the Windows 7 Pro computer where the Intel 2-port NIC is installed:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 21...00 1b 21 36 c2 79 ......Intel(R) Gigabit ET Dual Port Server Adapter #2
 20...00 1b 21 36 c2 78 ......Intel(R) Gigabit ET Dual Port Server Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.105     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.105    266
    192.168.1.105  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    266
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.3.2    266
      192.168.3.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.2    266
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.105    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.3.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.2    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 21    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    266 fe80::5c8a:c6bc:98b5:8f24/128
                                    On-link
 20    266 fe80::e1d9:f560:2020:1a98/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

This is my first attempt at a multi-homed Windows computer.  Can someone help me figure out how to get the `net use` command to successfully create a drive mapping on the Windows 10 192.168.3.3 computer from the Windows 7 Pro machine where the Intel NIC is installed?

Thanks In Advance For Your Help!

Comment: is this all the same physical network?

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, the only physical connection point between the two subnets is the 2-port Intel NIC.

Comment: if its the same network, and no need for a seperation i would suggest to use 255.255.0.0 as netmask and all target should reach each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was the most recent Windows 10 1903 upgrade (as of 8/12/2019).  It broke the Function Discovery Resource Publication service which prevented network discovery (the WS-Discovery protocol) from publishing the Windows 10 computer on the workgroup network which prevents it from appearing in Network Explorer **and from being able to be reached using** `net use`.  I posted my testing and findings about this issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/local-network-problems-with-1903/97086935-7cfe-4227-ac7f-87ecd46ad83b?page=3) for those that may be experiencing this problem.  Until Microsoft fixes this problem (I reported it to them via phone on 8/13/2019) the fix is to either start this service (if it wasn't started when the computer booted) or stop it and restart it if it is running.